# CSS PHP Bootstrap - Making navbar inverse for each page

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navbar on multiple pages on my website.  Each time I want to make a change to the navbar it is a pain having to go to each individual page and make the change.  **Goal**: I want to make my navbar editable in one place and affect every page that has it.

**I tried to** make the navbar code reside in a single separate PHP file, then include the php file in the page using PHP code

```
include 'page.php';
```

and then just call an echo statement to print out the navbar on whatever page I wanted, but that didnt work as planned for some reason?

```
echo $navbarCode;
```

How can I acheieve making one change to the navbar and make it update all pages including the navbar?

Comment: where and how did you define `$navbarCode`? a simple include inside all pages should work.

Comment: Let me try again real quick and then see what happens.  I did it over a week ago last. @Fred-ii-

Comment: what I always did/do was/is include the nav code inside one file and include that in every page. Make sure you don't have syntax errors. You shouldn't have to echo anything really, just including should do the job if you are using `.php` files and not `.html` if that's the case here.

Comment: So if you include a php file, it runs that php file each time that page is called correct? Assuming yes how would you control that the navbar go to where it needs to inside the page that is calling it? I was going to put the navbar code in the navbar.php and then echo the string variable out in the calling page? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Another problem I have is that there is php code interjected here and there in  the navbar code

Comment: you would need to post a minimal example of what your files are. If by including a file and you have variables in there that other pages rely on, then the order of the include could have a bearing on this.

Answer (score 0):

you have to name everyfile as .php file.

and then your navbar.php would more or less look like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar-contain">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-div" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
          </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-div">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs">
              <li><a href="#chicken-div">Chicken</a></li>
              <li><a href="#beef-div">Beef</a></li>
              <li><a href="#sushi-div">Sushi</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

Now if you want to add navbar.php in some file page.php then add this snippet:

```
include'navbar.php';
```

You dont have to use an echo statement since there are no variables in this code.

Comment: Thanks Atul but I DO have variables in my code. Havent had a chance to work on this again yet.